# Count the number of threads created by Task.Run()

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

I am benchmarking the performance of the `BlockingCollection`.

```
class Program
{
    private static BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>(100000);
    private static BlockingCollection<int> bc2 = new BlockingCollection<int>(100000);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            bc.TryAdd(i);

        }

        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        while (bc.Count != 0)
        {
            bc.Take();
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Simple " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        createThreadPool(bc2);



        Console.Read();
    }

    static void ByTaskRun(BlockingCollection<int> blockingCollection)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            blockingCollection.TryAdd(i);

        }
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Task k = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (blockingCollection.Count != 0)
            {
                blockingCollection.Take();
            }
        });

        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Task.run " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

In the `main()` method, I simply take the elements from a blocking collection while in `ByTaskRun()` I run a task to take the elements out. I found that `Task.Run()` is a faster one. Does it create a `Threadpool` internally? If I want to to get the number of threads created by the `Task.Run`, how can I get that number?

Comment: Look at the size of the .net ThreadPool, as this is where the work will be scheduled by default in a Console app. BlockingCollection is a poor man's BufferBlock when it comes to queueing stuff. Take a look at TPL DataFlow to see a properly asynchronous way of coordinating work on the ThreadPool (or whereever).

Comment: You can also check Process.Threads. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What can I do to create let's say 4 threads to remove those 100000 records from my blocking collection?

Comment: Um. You're starting your task in the background with `Task.Run`, and then immediately stopping your stopwatch *without waiting for the task to finish.* Heck, you're not even waiting for it to *start* - it might not have gotten its first slice of CPU time by the time you're calling `Console.WriteLine`. The elapsed time you're outputting is total garbage.

Comment: @JoeWhite Thanks for letting me know that. I didn't know that I was getting the incorrect elapsed time i.e. while the task was still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this sample `Task.Run()` use only **one** thread.
And you get not actual working duration.

Comment: I think you should give additional emphasis to the word *use* (as opposed to *create*). Task.Run only queues up the task in the default scheduler, which uses the ThreadPool. Under normal circumstances, no thread will be created. If the ThreadPool is under load, it *may* create more threads. Maybe.

Comment: what if I want to consume the elements by creating more than one thread? How should I create more threads?

Comment: If you call Task.Run in each loop

Comment: What can I do to create let's say 4 threads to remove those 100000 records from my blocking collection?